# Saving two new related objects in one request

Tags: rest, ember.js, json-api

I have two models in Django:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class ThreadMessage(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name='messages')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

Now a client wants to create a new thread with first message in it. It has first to do a `POST /threads` to create a new thread and find out its `id` and then do `POST /messages` passing the found id in `thread` field.

I am thinking if it's reasonable and possible to do all of this in one request from Ember like:

```
POST /messages 
{"message": {"text": "text", ...},
 "thread":  {"entity": 1}}
```

And the response would be:

```
{"message": {"text": "text", "id": 5678, "thread": 1234, ...},
 "thread":  {"entitity": 1, "id": 1234, ...}}
```

Comment: I think this posts would anwser your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26823614/4322950 however this would supose that you deal properly with the ember request format in Django. If it's note the case you have still options with store.push and store.pushpayload with the answer of a custom ajax call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly reasonable.

People seem to interpret REST in a very strange and largely ignorant way. A cursory read of the [HTTP RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) for POST and PUT will confirm you are on solid ground.

A resource representation can represent ANYTHING.  The key thing is to preserve the semantics of the REST operations. So PUT can be used for both CREATE and REPLACE like operations (I tend to think of PUT being REPLACE rather than UPDATE as REPLACE is closer to an idempotent semantic than UPDATE in my mind)

A PUT to an endpoint where supported, should accept whatever representation a GET returns. A POST can do literally anything you want as it doesn't need to support idempotent semantics.

HTTP and REST is designed and intended to support resource representations that may overlap other resources and the RFC is explicit about this.  You do this all the time when doing a GET on a collection endpoint.

You are NOT breaking REST by having a thread containing a child message in a single request and IMO that is a very valid use use case for sane referential integrity on the server.  Any time a transactional semantic is required, a POST or PUT is perfectly valid to create a graph of objects on the server in a single request. It is really simple, if you can GET it in a single request, you should be able to PUT it in a single request, so think carefully about your URL's and parameters.

For example, you may have a thread endpoint that returns all messages and that endpoint may support a parameter to just return some subset of the information `/api/threads?include=hasRead` which returns just `id` and `hasRead` for each message in the thread, or perhaps just some range of 'pages'. You can then PUT using that same endpoint and parameters and just update  the`hasRead` property in bulk.

Anyone who gets hung up on this has probably never considered access controls either. Access control necessitates a different view of a resource from one user to another based on what they are allowed to access.  This different view of a resource is conveyed in HTTP auth headers and/or in the request URL; again REST is not being broken by sub-setting or overlapping resources.

So go ahead and create the minimal graph of objects you need and either PUT or POST them.  I use V4 UUID's so clients can assign ID's (and thus resource endpoints) themselves and this allows me to use PUT for both create and replace like actions and wire up complex object graphs without client<->server id mapping issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree with your arguments. I have upvoted your answer,but will not accept it, as this topic looks controversial. Thanks for the idea with UUIDs, though I have integer ids.

Comment: I also use Ember Data to serialize multiple objects into the response. Ember Data out of the box supports embedded records with the EmbeddedRecordsMixin http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html so I don't regard this as particularly controversial or 'breaking Ember' as claimed by others

Comment: I like sideloading, because it includes each relatedrecord only once. We are already using sideloading, is switching to embedded records the only solution?

Comment: You can definitely use side-loading when retrieving data, the Ember Data store will push any side loaded data into the appropriate model collection for you automatically.  Saving models without using the embedded record mixin will require you to override the serialize() or serializeHasMany() on for your model specific serializer to side-save the message(s) if the thread is new.

Answer (score -4):

What you are trying to do will be break concept of REST and EmberJS itself.

If you have two separate APIs `you should make two REST calls.`

First save the parent `thread` model , after successful return save the child `message`. Then use [addObject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_addObject) to reflect changes in views.

This is best way. Don't try to optimize by reducing API calls here and breaking REST in the way.

Comment: It's not just optimizing. If something happens to the network, I could end up with orphaned threads.

Comment: @warvariuc use rollback in such case to remove the parent :)

Comment: You mean on server side? It's impossible, a transaction works within a single request. On client?\

Comment: @warvariuc parent(save) -> done -> child(save) -> fail -> deleteRecord(child) -> deleteRecord(parent) , everything clean

Comment: Anf what if on the first step `parent(save)` you've got network problems and the parent was actually saved, but you don't know this? You've got an orphaned thread.

Comment: Your parent is saved but you have network problem. How both things can occur at same time. Do you mean client end?

Comment: You send a request `parent(save)` and server responds, but the response doesn't arrive (proxy problems, network connectivity), so the client gets a timeout or other network error, and it thinks the parent wasn't saved, but it was.

Comment: If its that important(mission critical) to handle network syncs may be REST only is not what you should use. But you can use reload method to even pull that off.